Estimating number of product of $k-$primes upto given $x$
We know that up to $x$ the number of primes can be estimated by
$$\pi(x) = x \prod_{p \leq \sqrt{x}} \left(1 - \frac{1}{p}\right)$$
Can we extend this type of argument to estimate the number of terms up to $x$ which are a product of exactly $k$ primes?
I tried to use this for a product of $2$ primes:
$$x \prod_{p \leq x^{1/3}} \left( 1 - \frac{1}{p} \right)$$
But this is not matching with the number of terms I obtained using Python. Can someone help me with a reasoning for this type of estimate?

The first sentence is incorrect: the left-hand side is asymptotic to $x/\log x$, but the right-hand side is asymptotic to $2e^{-\gamma} x/\log x$. As for the correct asymptotic formula for $k$-primes, see my answer to a related MathOverflow question.
